# Animate layout background image changes

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to animate the background image of a layout (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.) in Android? In one of my applications I am fetching an image from the internet and displaying it as the background image once it's loaded. It would be really cool if the background image was swapped out using a fade effect or something like that.

I've tried quite a bit, but couldn't seem to find a solution. It's always the layout that's animating and not the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be your best bet to just layer your layout in a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` with a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) behind it. See the [demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html) (and related layouts) in the Android API Demos app (that uses an ImageSwitcher, which is a special-case adapter-based subclass of `ViewSwitcher`). It does mean an extra `ViewGroup` level in your app, but unless you're doing something especially complicated (nesting these in `ListView` rows or something) it should perform just fine, and handles the transition animations for you.

You could also just use [WebImageView](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/widgets/WebImageView.java) from [DroidFu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu), which does most of the annoying legwork for you.